# Implement an algorithm to find the nearest place

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a simple web app to find the nearest place from a given position.  What I want do is: taken my position through geolocation function in Google maps, find the nearest place in a map.  A list of places to be considered is saved in a MySQL db.  Every record has two fields: latitude and longitude.  After parsing these two values I need to calculate the distance and obtain the nearest place.  How can I use JavaScript and PHP to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for this: [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html).

As a plus, you may want to find the nearest 50 elements and then use the [Distance Matrix Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix.html) to see how far they are in practice (by driving/walking) to cut down those inital 50 nearest places to those that are the nearest in practice.