# Google Maps geocoder to find nearby places from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a website where I store locations in a MySQL database and GeoCode using the address provided by the database.

Now I want to add a feature which will find the closest places to the specified point e.g. the location they are standing now or typing. I'm coding the geocoder and google maps in JavaScript and jQuery and I get the results using PHP to fetch from the database.

I read about the `viewport` but I can't figure out how it would work in my situation where I need to show my own database locations and not Google's.

Can anybody help? And it would be awesome if you have some kind of example.

Comment: Please give a concrete example. I mean, an actual address you are using. I am confused by your question.

Comment: If e.g i wanted to find a specific bar in copenhagen i would save the address e.g "Vester voldgade 10 København V", send it to the geocoder and display it in google maps using the lat and longitude i get. Now i want to find places nearby this bar and display them.

Comment: So `Vester voldgade 10` is in your database, and you want to find other bars near Vester Voldgade 10?

Comment: Yes for example. But it could also be an address specified by the user, and then return all results within 1 kilometer or 500 yards or something.

Comment: This is a pure SQL question, not Google Maps or PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement an algorithm to find the nearest place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175282/implement-an-algorithm-to-find-the-nearest-place)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

radius search:

```
select *,
    acos(cos(centerLat * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(centerLon * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lat * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lon * (PI()/180))
     +
     cos(centerLat * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(centerLon * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lat * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(lon * (PI()/180))
     +
     sin(centerLat * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(lat * (PI()/180))
    ) * 3959 as Dist
from TABLE_NAME
having Dist < radius
order by Dist
```

3959 is the Earth radius in Miles. Replace this value with
radius in KM, or any unit, to get results on the same unit.
**centerLat** and **centerLon** are the center of the search (your
input), while lat and lon are fields in the table.

Comment: where do you get centerlat from?

Comment: Did you read the *entire post*? (including the note below the code)?

Comment: sorry must have skipped that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

- Since you use a database anyway, convert and save the human-readable address to a LatLng (once) every time you add a place to your DB
- Query user for his/her location
- geocode the user location to a LatLng
- use a SQL query to find places matching desired distance. (see here https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)

`SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;`

- display SQL results back to Javascript map

Comment: i thought about saving my lat/longs, and that is a good idea. Thank you i will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the classic store locator.  See this [article in the Google Maps API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) for an example using PHP and MySQL.